# "error: operator does not exist: integer[] = integer" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to execute following stored procedure using PostgreSQL but it gives me this error. Is this query is not correct?

**"error: operator does not exist: integer[] = integer"**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.parkingvehicle(
    IN p_dui text,
    IN p_desired_parking_id text,
    IN p_vehicle_no text,
    IN p_temp_id integer,
    OUT p_result integer)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    user_id_val int;
    vehicle_no_val text;
BEGIN
    -- Execute the first query
    SELECT user_id, vehicle_no INTO user_id_val, vehicle_no_val
    FROM users
    WHERE dui = p_dui::int;

    -- Check if the user_id is null
    IF user_id_val IS NULL THEN
        -- Insert into temp_login table
        INSERT INTO temp_login(dui, vehicle_no, temp_id)
        VALUES (p_dui, p_vehicle_no, p_temp_id);

        -- Update parking table
        UPDATE parking 
        SET is_equipped = true, equipped_by = p_temp_id, equipped_time = now(), vehicle_no = p_vehicle_no
        WHERE parking_id = p_desired_parking_id;

        -- Set the result to 0 to indicate failure
        p_result := 0;
    ELSE
        -- Execute the second query
        UPDATE parking 
        SET is_equipped = true, equipped_by = user_id_val, equipped_time = now(), vehicle_no = vehicle_no_val
        WHERE parking_id = p_desired_parking_id;
        
        -- Set the result to 1 to indicate success
        p_result := 1;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
```

I do not even pass any array when calling this query.
My table are like follows.

[image: temp logins]

[image: users]

Comment: Could you please share the entire error message? And the DDL for all tables involved? It could be that one of the columns is an array.

Comment: Please don't use images, just plain text. And the (original) DDL, how to create the tables. And also the complete error message, because there should be more.

Comment: By the way, why do you use p_dui text when dui is an integer? This will fail on text input: p_dui::int